# Have other series used picture cast credits besides The World is Still Beautiful?

Tags: anime-production, the-world-is-still-beautiful

The closing credits of *The World is Still Beautiful* give their cast credits with pictures of each character, as they appear in that episode, along with the voice actor's name. (At least I am assuming that is what the text says.) For example, from episode 11:

[image: from end credits of episode 11]

This seems like an extremely good way to give credit, just as do many movies and live action TV shows. But it struck me that I don't remember any other anime series doing it. Have other series done so?

Comment: Like the Opening of Baccano (2007) or does it only count if the seiyuu is mentioned alongside the character's name?